# How to generate the proper url when rendering partial view through ajax in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

my problem is such that i'm trying to create a blog using as much ajax as i can so instead of rendering full views, everytime a user clicks on a navigation link a partial view generates trough ajax call but my url does not change, and when i manually type home/blog only partial view generates the html and no main layout..

this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Blog()
        {
            var rep = repository.FindAllPosts().ToList();    
                return PartialView(rep);
        }
```

this is my Blog View:

```
@model IEnumerable<SpongleMVC.Models.Post>

@if (User.Identity.Name == "alanik")
{
    <div id="adminPostPanel">
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Create Post", "CreatePost", new AjaxOptions()
{

    UpdateTargetId = "main"
})
    </div>
}

@Html.Partial("_PartialPostList", (System.Collections.IEnumerable)Model)
```

and this is the ajax call in my layout page to open the Blog partial view:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Blog", "Blog", new AjaxOptions()
               {

                   UpdateTargetId = "main"
               })
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the whole point with AJAX. Urls do not change. If you change them the browser redirects. You could implement a solution using url fragments (`#`). You could manipulate the url after the `#` sign without redirect. This allows to handle history with AJAX. There are also plugins for jQuery such as [this one](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) that might enable history with AJAX calls and as a consequence the Back/Next buttons.

If you want your application also to work without AJAX you could test in your controller action whether the request was done using Ajax (`Request.IsAjaxRequest()`) and return a full view instead of a partial. So if a user types directly the url in hist browser he will see a full page with a layout and not only a partial.

---

UPDATE:

I suspect that your Ajax.ActionLink doesn't work as expected because you forgot to include the following script:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That's what will make those Ajax.* helpers perform Ajax requests in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

Comment: so let me get this straight, there is no way to generate partial views in my main layout, (i don't want the main layout to refresh itself, only popup different partial views through ajax) and as i do it i still want my url to change, from home to home/blog after blog link was clicked? its impossible? i need rethink my solution? is there any way to do this but i don't want to refresh the whole page just parts of it, and in the same time the adress to change?

Comment: @alan, of course that it's possible. That's what Ajax.ActionLink does. See my update about the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script that you probably forgot to include if you are saying that the Ajax.ActionLink performs a full postback instead of an Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it like that.

From a SEO point of view as well as a user's it's horrible navigation.

I would load blog posts as separate pages, so spiders can follow your links and users and other websites can link directly to your posts.

Use AJAX wisely, don't try to make everything AJAX driven.

Comment: yes but this is just going to be my "designers website blog" that uses concept of a one page application, i really like the idea but i guess it's not as easy as it sounds, but thanks for this info tho

Comment: i want my site to look more like a flash website, no refreshing u know

Comment: So why does the url have to change? It wouldn't change if you used flash. And if you want people to know the url to a post, include a 'permalink' which they can click to load the post directly and bookmark it.

Comment: hmm well it's actually not that important, but just better visual result, i was just wondering if it's even possible but i guess not, but also another point, i got some other actions that redirect to blog action, so when we redirect the partial view shows up as a full view, and i dont want that, i want to see the whole layout with the ajax partial view in it, so i'm still figuring out that to do